# "Uncaught Object" Error while loading requirejs

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am using requirejs-backbone to display list of users:However I'm getting this "Uncaught Object" error when i load the page. I debugged it and saw its my main.js that is causing the trouble. Below is my main.js.

```
 require.config({
   baseUrl: 'scripts/modules/sub-accounts/',
    paths: {

    'underscore': '../../libs/underscore',
    'backbone': '../../libs/backbone',
    'views': 'views',
    'collections': 'collections',
    'models': 'models',
    'templates': 'templates'

},
shim: {
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    },
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['jquery', "underscore"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    },
    'bootstrap': {
        deps: ['jquery']
       }

   }

 });

  require([
       'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
         'router'
     ], function ($, _, backbone, router){

  SubAccountRouter.initialize();

});
```

EDIT:::

This is the place(init.js file) where im initializing all my scripts, apps and other libraries apart from the config in main.js. I'm not sure is that might be causing the issue:

```
          script : [
            '/scripts/libs/require/require.js',
    '/scripts/libs/require/text.js',
    '/scripts/libs/underscore.js',  
    '/scripts/libs/backbone.js',    
            '/scripts/modules/sub-accounts/main.js',
    '/scripts/modules/sub-accounts/router.js'
          ]
```

Any ideas as to where i might be going wrong??

Comment: Why do you think it’s `main.js` that’s the problem? On which line does the error happen?

Comment: The very first line. I tried deleting main.js and router.js and the error goes away. but when i include content in it, throws the error. I put a debugger on the first line: "  require.config({ "  and it break there with the error: Uncaught object. this is my perception, something else might be going on..I'm clueless though..

Comment: Hmm. Presumably it’s really an error in one of the required files. What if you remove everything in the call to `config` and build it up step by step?

Comment: well i happen to try put something like this: require.config({ }); basically removing everything inside the config to see if the paths are causing issue, but no luck...its the same. I'm wondering if its in in my ordering of files: in my init.js i have files loaded:              require.js                                                          text.js                                                              jquery.js and then underscore, backbone.js and so on.. i also tried in the order where jquery.js                      json.js and then the rest, still no luck..:( any idea??

Comment: Have you tried placing "jquery" into the require.config?  Cause since you're not stating it, it's assuming to find "jquery" at 'scripts/modules/sub-accounts/jquery.js'.  Is that where it is?  Also where is "bootstrap"?  I don't see it in the require.config paths

Comment: yes, i have tried adding the jquery and the bootstrap to the config, but now change. I'm wondering if this might be the error: there are 2 places where im initializing all the paths to the folder. 1) the init.js file that has all the paths to the scripts, libraries, apps. 2) the require.config() in the main.js file. I'm sure its taking the path from the init.js file coz, if i remove any files from there, it throws error. This is my guess. Do you have any suggestions over this. Thanks!

Comment: If `require.config({})` is still throwing the error, try commenting out the `require`. If that doesn't throw the error, you're likely not loading RequireJS before the `config` call...

Comment: this is the way below im adding my urls to load, with requirejs at the top followed by the libraries and then my main.js script : [
            '/scripts/libs/require/require.js',
    '/scripts/libs/require/text.js',
    '/scripts/libs/underscore.js',  
    '/scripts/libs/backbone.js',    
            '/scripts/modules/sub-accounts/main.js',
    '/scripts/modules/sub-accounts/router.js'
          ], is there something i need to change the order?

Comment: i also tried removing the require and just calling the config(). it threw the same error..im going nuts with this error..:(

Comment: Did you come to a conclusion?

Comment: not really, i had to do some work around in my existing code to get this work. I still get the error,but that aint preventing me to go ahead with my implementation. I wish i find some concrete solution to this

Comment: Could you provide the stack trace of the error?